# Good way to maintain Qt labels and text on UI

Tags: c++, qt

What is the best way/common practice for maintaining all string resources found on a UI in Qt, especially the textual input/text in combo boxes etc. (since these are the once that are frequently used in the code itself)?

I know that Android has this string resources thing such that resources only have to be modified at one position.

Does Qt have something like that too or do I have to initialize string resources in code instead of in the UI's XML itself...

Comment: Just saying, for `QComboBox` you may call `QComboBox::model` to access the `QAbstractItemMode` which contains the text. This model can also be used in another view such as `QListView`. As for `QLabel`, it seems the best way to manage those string text is creating labels with pure code instead of using the ui designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in mechanism for string resources in Qt. If you want to maintain strings at build time you can define them in one .h/.cpp file as global variables and reuse them in your code.

Otherwise you can use [Qt's translator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-translators.html) files (binary) and load them along with your application. If you need to change a string, you simply will need to edit the translation file (xml) and "recompile" it with [lrelease](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-manager.html#lrelease) utility without building the application again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism to dynamically translate texts in application, but it works a bit different than Android string resources, but achieves the same goals.

Qt uses i18n system modelled after standard, well known unix `gettext`. It works in a very similar way to iOS `NSLocalizedString`, if that rings a bell.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#tr

This is worth reading too:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html

Android approach is a bit unique and you should not expect it to be a "standard everywhere". It works, it's ok, but it's not a standard way of doing things on desktop.